# How can I create a signature box and submit(post) that signature to another page using php?

Tags: php, post, signature

I have an `HTML` form where a user has fields to fill and at the end there is a signature where user has to sign.  I then want all the data to be posted to another page.  I posted all the fields, but I just can't post the signature

This is my signature box and its is working,

[image: sig box]

I am using a signature library from [keith signature library](http://keith-wood.name/)
but I just cant post the signature to another page

Comment: Read the docs http://keith-wood.name/signature.html and http://keith-wood.name/signatureRef.html > commands tab > $(selector).signature('toJSON'). You need to make it json to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

This is so easy you can save it as SVG by putting hidden field in your form with id someHiddenText after click or you can change event to before form submit or whatever then putting the SVG code in this hidden field.

```
$('#svgButton').click(function() { 
    $('#someHiddenText').val($('#captureSignature').signature('toSVG'));
});
```