# Can we create place for Applicant's Signature in a <form> using HTML only? If yes then how? I have no idea. I don't know any html tag of that kind

Tags: html

I want to take Applicant's Signature in my form which I have created using just HTML. It's just a form layout created by using HTML. I saw many Online forms that have signature too. But I don't know how to do that.

I tried using input tag with text then it didn't workout. Text was being typed and not signature.

Comment: _"I saw many Online forms that have signature too."_ Example, please? Have you seen [How can I create a signature box and submit(post) that signature to another page using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104353/how-can-i-create-a-signature-box-and-submitpost-that-signature-to-another-page)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.